# How can I change Finder tag name or color?

Tags: macos, finder, finder-tag

There are some tags in Finder by default. I want rename their name from color. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Finder → Preferences → Tags. You can rename/delete tags by right-clicking and modify the coloured tags with the control at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Good tag names!

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is right-click on the tag in the sidebar of finder

[image]

and click on the colour you want the tag to be

Comment: Keep in mind not all tags are listed in the sidebar.